# SSRS show the zero after a decimal in text box

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, decimal, zero, decimalformat

I have a text Box in my report to show the numerical value of the data in the graph.

I have created an Expression consisting of both text and data value.

I have used `Round to show the first integer after the decimal`, but when a number is for example: `"80.0"` it shows it as `"80"`. I would like the text Box to show values that have a zero after the decimal.

Below is the Expression I have used in the text Box:

```
="Desired text in text box: " & Round(Avg(Fields!MyData.Value, "MyDataSet"),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below expression,

```
="Desired text in text box: " & Format(CInt(Round(Avg(Fields!MyData.Value, "MyDataSet"),1)),"N2")
```

Answer (score 0):

enter N2 in the format property of the textbox (for 2 decimal places is N2)